# change numbering in table of content for Beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, numbering

I want to use roman number for section and bullet for subsection in TOC for Beamer as shown in this figure:
[image]

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: the default theme.

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Is it that what you want?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, the align is not the same for section and subsections. I want to use the same align as given in the figure above. Also, there is a long horizontal space between bullet and subsection name. Is there anyway to reduce spacing between bullet and subsection name?

Comment: Sure. Please see my udated answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I am a little curious. I think I saw the answer as accepted and now it is not, so is my answer still lacking something? Is there anything else missing? Please, don't think I am forcing you to acept the answer; I just want to know if there's still something else that my answer is still missing.

Comment: Excuse me, it seems that I twice clicked on the button. It's all OK now. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, OK. No need to apologize :) I just thought that there was something still missing. Thanks for accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with a definition of the `section in toc` and  `subsection in toc` templates:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\defbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{bullets}{%
  \leavevmode
  \parbox[t]{1em}{\textbullet\hfill}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1em\relax}{\inserttocsubsection}\par}
\defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{sections numbered roman}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \MakeUppercase{\romannumeral\inserttocsectionnumber}.\ %
  \inserttocsection\par}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered roman]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[bullets]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Préliminaires}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Operateurs}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Quelques notions}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Echauffement: la derivée}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]