# Numbering by letters in beamer table of contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

In this question, it is explained how to change table of contents numbering to Roman numerals in `beamer`: [change numbering in table of content for Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163485/change-numbering-in-table-of-content-for-beamer).

I would like to change it to uppercase letters. How could this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the initial part to

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\defbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{bullets}{%
  \parbox[t]{1em}{\textbullet\hfill}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1em\relax}{\inserttocsubsection}\par}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{sections numbered roman}{%
  \@Alph\inserttocsectionnumber.\ %
  \inserttocsection\par}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered roman]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[bullets]

\begin{document}
```

[image]