# Beamer - numbering of sections in appendix TOC with A, B, C

Tags: beamer

I would like to have the sections in the appendix numbered with letters A, B, C...
The answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268024/numbering-by-letters-in-beamer-table-of-contents) is to change the numbering for the whole document, but I would like to have this only for the appendix. How can I acheieve this. Thanks for your help.

So my document will look like so

```
Main document TOC
1 - First section
2 - Second section
3 - Third section

Apendix TOC

A - Appendix A
B - Appendix B
C - Appendix C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!!! Using the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268024/numbering-by-letters-in-beamer-table-of-contents) which I cited in my question, all I had to do was remove

`\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered roman]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[bullets]`

from the preamble and place it just before `\appendix`.