# How to number sections in Roman numerals in a Beamer header?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, header-footer

I am using Beamer and the Warsaw theme. I am trying to format the way sections appear in the frame header.

What I would like to get in header:

I - Section I

II - Section II

I did not manage to modify the numbering to uppercase roman letters. Here is a minimal example :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\makeatletter
\def\insertsectionheadnumber{\@Roman\c@section}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}%
{\hfil\insertsectionheadnumber~-~\insertsectionhead}

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}%
{\color{structure!50}\hfil\insertsectionheadnumber~-~\insertsectionhead}

\begin{document}

\section{Section I}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Subsection II}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What I tried so far to add in my preamble:

- `\renewcommand \thesection{\Roman{section}}`: not working because Beamer uses `\insertsectionheadnumber` to insert the section number instead of the standard counter.
- `\renewcommand \insertsectionheadnumber{\Roman{section}}`: I get the error `\insertsectionheadnumber undefined`.
- `\makeatletter
  \def\insertsectionheadnumber{\@Roman\c@section}
  \makeatother`
  No error produced but it appears to have no effect.
- Using `\insertsectionnumber` instead of `\insertsectionheadnumber`. Here, the `\def` command is working (numbers appear as roman), but *all* the sections are numbered with the counter of the *current* one (so in my example, on slide 1 every section will be numbered I, then on slide 2 they will all be numbered II).

I tried to look into the class files and found that `\insertsectionheadnumber` is defined in `beamerbasenavigation.sty`, but I don't understand the code I found there.

How should I define the `\insertsectionheadnumber` command, or is there another (better) way to do this ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163490/36296 you can use `\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral\insertsectionheadnumber}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}%
{\hfil \MakeUppercase{\romannumeral\insertsectionheadnumber}~-~\insertsectionhead}

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}%
{\color{structure!50}\hfil \MakeUppercase{\romannumeral\insertsectionheadnumber}~-~\insertsectionhead}

\begin{document}

\section{Section I}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Subsection II}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's working, thanks! I had seen the `\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered roman]` and tried to apply it to section in header/footer, but I had not seen the rest of the code.